# Get the values from each td

Tags: php, parsing, phpquery

I am using phpQuery to get the data from elements.

I'm trying to get the values from first `td`, seconds `td` and `href` link from each `tr`.

```
<table>
  <tr class="A2"> 
    <td> Text 1 </td>
    <td> Text 2 </td>
    <td> Text 3 </td>
    <td> <a href="linkhere1">  Text 131</a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="A2"> 
    <td> Text 4 </td>
    <td> Text 5 </td>
    <td> Text 6 </td>
    <td> <a href="linkhere2">  Text 123213</a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="A2"> 
    <td> Text 7 </td>
    <td> Text 8 </td>
    <td> Text 9 </td>
    <td> <a href="linkhere3.php">  Text 213213 </a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to do this? I have tried:

```
<?
require('phpQuery.php');

$file = file_get_contents('test.txt', true);

$html = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

foreach($html->find('.A2')  as $tag) {                                           
  echo pq('td'); // problem here?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you have them switched..

```
foreach(pq('.A2') as $tag) {
   $tds = pq($tag)->find('td');
}
```

To get a value from each td, you can iterate over it inside:

```
foreach(pq('.A2') as $tag) {
   foreach(pq($tag)->find('td') as $td) {
      // stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: I forgot that they are pure DOMNode when iterating on them. You have to wrap with `pq()` again.

Answer (score 2):

`pq()` would return a list of matching nodes (your `<td>` tags, in this case). You have to iterate over that list:

```
foreach(pq('td') as $td) {
   ... do something ...
}
```

Comment: How would you get the first td and second td from the list? and value?